# Как сделать корректной верстку в Safari на iOS?

Tags: css, вёрстка, safari

Всем привет. Выполняю верстку элементов интернет-магазина и застрял на моменте в Safari браузерах. 
Прикладываю два скриншота. 
1 - как должно быть и как есть в остальных браузерах
и 2 - как отображается в Safari.
[image: Как должно быть]
[image: Как отображается в Safari]

```css
.cat-product-price {
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vm3pr-2 cat-product-price">
 <div class="product-price" id="productPrice1366">
  <div class="PricesalesPrice vm-display vm-price-value">
   <span class="vm-price-desc">Цена: </span>
   <span class="PricesalesPrice">7044 ₽</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Какие есть способы решения данной проблемы?

Comment: а как насчет самого кода? очень бы помогло... даже больше, чем скриншоты.

Comment: absolute и float - уже странно выглядит. Так же нужно обязательно указывать, если есть абсолют относительно каких сторон ему выравниваться: top/bottom/left/right. Не все браузеры могут гордиться тем, что автоматически выставляют положение абсолютного элемента к родителю.

Comment: Всё, добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, дело в кроссбраузерности.

Попробуйте скопировать ваш код https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/ сюда, и после преобразования стилей вставьте в свой файл стилей.

Также если версия ios маленькая( ios =< 6), многие стили работают некорректно.